# how to understand the locality of variables in Mathematica

Tags: replacement, variable, rule

(in the first i should say may be the title is not very accurate)

how to understand case like the following:

```
Clear[x,f];
Replace[f[1],f[x_]->x+1] (*ans is 2*)
x=10;
Replace[f[1],f[x_]->x+1] (*ans is 11*)
```

this kind behavior of Mathematica make me feel unsafe when i use variable, that means if i happen to define x in another place, then the Replace[] I wrote here will be wrong, so I have to be very careful with the renaming of variable names.

questions:

1. how to understand case in the above? why grammar of Mathematica can't be design so that the x_ in Replace is local(ie won't be influenced by the outside x)?
2. In addition to the approach -- pay attention not use same variable name in Replace[], is there another way which can save my attention?

Comment: Try `RuleDelayed`  `:>` instead of `->`.

Comment: "->" will evaluate the right hand side at once and take whatever values are available for the variables. However, ":>" waits until it is applied and the variables have been matched to corresponding values. The mechanism used with ":>" is similar to "Block", loock it up in the manual.

Comment: To add to the comments above, I find it convenient and safer to use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) whenever the left-hand side portion of the replacement rule contains a named pattern. This avoids exactly the kinds of problems you see here. Although there may well be cases where this would not be appropriate, for general use I find that there are practically no downsides to defaulting to `:>` when dealing with named patterns.